# django instance.id=None

Tags: python, django, instance

I'd like to save a profil photo for each user.instance.id is returning None when upload image.I'm waiting for your help.

**models.py**

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.id, "profil.png")

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

**froms.py**

```
from .models import UserProfile


class image(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = image(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = image()
    return render(request, 'model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**model_form_upload.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question. Note that this is explicitly mentioned in the [documentation for `upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference `instance.id` at this point as the instance is not created yet, hence it doesn't have an id. Therefore, could either use a different model field, or user an id of a child element. Check the docs for the example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 0):

you can create a model instance by passing cleaned data from your form as **kwargs to django model i did it that way & its much easier than anything else

iam naming the path according to owner field which refers to user model of django

in your views post method add this (this code is from my project not adapted to this question)

```
    pk = request.session['_auth_user_id']
    user_obj = User.objects.get(pk=pk)


    lab_form_instance = lab_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
    lab_form_instance.save(commit=False)
    # here you can put the form.is_valid() statement
    lab_form_instance.cleaned_data['owner'] =user_obj # here iam adding additional needed data for the model
    obj = lab(**lab_form_instance.cleaned_data)
    obj.save()
```

*django==4.1